# File is not created after another has been created

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to create 2 XML files in the same folder.
For some reason it does create the first one, but does not create the second one.

Could it be that the first one is still being created when an attempt to create the second file is made, and therefore the latter fails?

I don't get any errors with the code:

```
if (File.Exists(FileNameTextBox.Text + ".AA.xml"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already exists. renaming to *.old" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "if there is already an *.old file, this will be deleted.");
    if (File.Exists(FileNameTextBox.Text + ".AA.xml.old"))
    {
        File.Delete(FileNameTextBox.Text + ".AA.xml.old");
    }
    File.Move(FileNameTextBox.Text + ".AA.xml", FileNameTextBox.Text + ".AA.xml.old");
}
if (!File.Exists(FileNameTextBox.Text + ".AA.xml"))
{
    XmlTextWriter textWritter = new XmlTextWriter(FileNameTextBox.Text + ".AA.xml", null);
    textWritter.WriteStartDocument();
    textWritter.WriteStartElement("Data");
    textWritter.WriteEndElement();
    textWritter.Close();
}

if (File.Exists("BB.xml"))
{
    if (File.Exists("BB.xml.old"))
    {
        File.Delete("BB.xml.old");
    }
    File.Move("BB.xml", "BB.xml.old");
}
if (!File.Exists("BB.xml"))
{
    XmlTextWriter textWritterPC3 = new XmlTextWriter("BB.xml", null);
    textWritterPC3.WriteStartDocument();
    textWritterPC3.WriteStartElement("Data");
    textWritterPC3.WriteEndElement();
    textWritterPC3.Close();
}
```

Comment: Try using else instead of another if. That may be where the bug is conning from

Comment: And try to build your filenames once and put them into string variables which you then use in all File functions.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: If he does so, the file will not be generated again if it existed in the first place. The way he does it, if the file exists, the file is moved to a backup file. If that succeeds, the file is created.

Comment: Do you have try/catch around this code block? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Is it a typo that in the line "if (!File.Exists("BB.xml")) //            {" the opening parenthesis are in a comment? If it is the case only the following line would be related to the if clause but then also the textWritterPC3 variable would not exist and there would be errors the following lines when it is accessed. I am a little bit confused ;-)

Comment: @DanielSchlößer The constant use of `BB.xml` will be optimized most likely so it only appears once in the executable, however, the constant string concations most likely won't until he uses `Release`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whats in `FileNameTextBox.Text`? Does it specify a directory path?

Your second file is created without saying which directory.  So it will be created in the current directory - which is not necessarily the directory specified by `FileNameTextBox.Text`

Comment: lol yea that was it! That explains why no error poped up. totally forgot to specify the path hehe. thanx!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying an absolute path for your file names, so you are using whatever the current directory happens to be, which is not reliable. Also you may need to call [DirectoryInfo.Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo_methods%28v=vs.90%29) or [FileInfo.Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_methods%28v=vs.90%29) to make sure you are seeing the latest directory information (whether the file exists or not).

Answer (score 0):

The comment is only making the last if case execute the first row.. The last if should look like this. I don't know if it's only in your example.
Your example

```
if (!File.Exists("BB.xml")) //            {
            XmlTextWriter textWritterPC3 = new XmlTextWriter("BB.xml", null);
```

should be

```
if (!File.Exists("BB.xml")) //            
{
    XmlTextWriter textWritterPC3 = new XmlTextWriter("BB.xml", null);
    textWritterPC3.WriteStartDocument();
    textWritterPC3.WriteStartElement("Data");

    textWritterPC3.WriteEndElement();
    textWritterPC3.Close();
}
```